# Как можно считать из переменной построчно?

Tags: c#

у меня имеется стринговая переменная с форматом данных:

```
1

2

3
```

Строки разделены переносами строк (0x0A,0x0D)

Как можно считать 1 потом 2 пропуска пробел между строками?

Answer (score 7):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string s =
@"1

2

3";

    string[] numbers = s.Split(new[] { '\n', '\r' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
}
```

Comment: в `numbers` будут находится все считанные строки?

Comment: потом можно сделать: `for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++) ?`

Comment: @Piubur в каждой ячейке элемента массива `numbers`, будут находиться только числа "1" "2" и "3" без пробелов и переносов строки.

Comment: могу я обращаться как по индексу ? я точно не знаю какой какие данные в строке

Comment: @Piubur, да, конечно. `numbers` - это обычный массив типа String. Можете почитать про массивы на MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/0a7fscd0.aspx

Comment: Может проще в байтах считывать? у меня формат данных умещается  в 94 байта.

Comment: Возможно стоит использовать `Environment.NewLine`, чтобы не зависеть от специфики ОС.

Comment: @АнтонБуторин, "чтобы зависеть" - без "не" ;)